# Setting tabindex using a userscript?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tabindex, scriptish

I work entering data online to a form that I would like to change the tabbing order but have had no luck using Greasemonkey and Scriptish.  I am able to remove tabindexes of -1 to make fields accessible in Scriptish.  However, whenever I try to set the `tabindex` on a field, the field ends up being skipped when tabbing.

This works to remove tabindex:

```
var eth = document.getElementById('Ethnicities-111');
if (eth)
eth.removeAttribute('tabindex');
```

This makes a different text area field inaccessible:

```
var tb = document.getElementById('EybComments');
if (tb)
tb.setAttribute('tabindex' '1');
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve the problem by assigning a tabindex of 1 to the first focusable element and then assigning tabindexes to the other fields in the order I desired.

Comment: Great!  Then [tick the check-mark next to the answer, below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

See [*Sequential focus navigation and the tabindex attribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute).  If you alter tab orders keep the following points in mind:

1. If `tabindex` is not set, then tab order flows naturally as described in the above spec.
2. If 2 elements have the same `tabindex`, the natural order will be used when within that `tabindex` value (see the demo below).
3. If the `tabindex` is negative, browsers normally won't allow that node to be tabbed to, *but browsers don't have to honor this rule*.
4. **If `tabindex` is removed, then the last used tab order may still apply (Firefox, etc.) rather than the natural order.**
   See the demo below.

This means that it is not enough to `removeAttribute('tabindex')` -- especially if it was set to -1!  You must set positive values and the positive values should make sense given the surrounding nodes and the desired taborder.

The following demo shows the effects of various types of `tabindex` ***changes***.
Note especially how **the "natural" order changes based on the previous `tabindex` values** before they were cleared.

Press the "Run code snippet" button, below.

```js
$("#startInp").focus ();

$("button").click ( function (zEvent) {
    $("#startInp")  .focus ();
    var targNodes   = $("td > label > input");
    targNodes.removeProp ("tabindex");
    $("#endInp")    .prop ("tabindex", "7")
                    .prev ("span").text ('Normal next in tab (ti=7)')
                    ;

    switch (zEvent.target.id) {
        case "btnUseNatural":
            targNodes.prev ("span").text ("tabindex not set");
            $("#endInp")    .prop ("tabindex", "2")
                            .prev ("span").text ('Normal next in tab (ti=2)')
                            ;
            break;

        case "btnUseSequential":
            targNodes.each ( function () {
                var jThis   = $(this);
                var tabIdx  = jThis.data ("tabidx");
                jThis.prop ("tabindex", tabIdx);
                jThis.prev ("span").text ('tabindex = ' + tabIdx);
            } );
            break;

        case "btnUseSawtooth":
            targNodes.each ( function () {
                var jThis       = $(this);
                var tabIdx      = jThis.data ("tabidx") + "";
                var newTabIdx   = 0;

                switch (tabIdx) {
                    case "1":   newTabIdx = 1;  break;
                    case "2":   newTabIdx = 3;  break;
                    case "3":   newTabIdx = 5;  break;
                    case "4":   newTabIdx = 2;  break;
                    case "5":   newTabIdx = 4;  break;
                    case "6":   newTabIdx = 6;  break;
                    case "-1":  newTabIdx = -1; break;
                }
                jThis.prop ("tabindex", newTabIdx);
                jThis.prev ("span").text ('tabindex = ' + newTabIdx);
            } );
            break;

        case "btnUseAllOnes":
        case "btnUseAllEights":
            var tabIdx      = zEvent.target.id == "btnUseAllOnes"  ?  "1"  :  "8";
            targNodes.prop ("tabindex", tabIdx);
            targNodes.prev ("span").text ('tabindex = ' + tabIdx);

            $('input[data-tabidx="-1"]').prop ("tabindex", "-1")
            .prev ("span").text ("tabindex = -1");
            ;
            break;
    }
} );
```

```css
div   { margin: -2ex auto 2em auto; }
input { margin: auto 2em auto 0.5ex; }
label > span {
    width: 14ex;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Set tab order to:</h2>
<div>
    <button id="btnUseNatural">Natural</button>
    <button id="btnUseSequential">Sequential</button>
    <button id="btnUseSawtooth">Sawtooth</button>
    <button id="btnUseAllOnes">All Ones</button>
    <button id="btnUseAllEights">All Eights</button>
</div>
<p> Tab around the following nodes to see the effect of tabindex changes.<br>
    <label>Start here  (ti=1):<input id="startInp" type="text" tabindex="1"></label>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="1" type="text"></label></td>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="2" type="text"></label></td>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="3" type="text"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><span>tabindex = -1</span>:<input data-tabidx="-1" tabindex="-1" type="text"></label></td>
        <td colspan="2"><=== Will almost always be skipped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="4" type="text"></label></td>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="5" type="text"></label></td>
        <td><label><span>tabindex not set</span>:<input data-tabidx="6" type="text"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <label><span>Normal next in tab (ti=2)</span>:<input id="endInp" type="text" tabindex="2"></label>
</p>
```